# Class based view won't work while function based view works(Django)

Tags: python, django, listview

When I try to create a function based view it would work, displaying my queryset. This is the code I used bellow.
in views.py

```
def restaurant_listview(request):
template_name ="restaurant/restaurantlist.html"
query_set = Restaurant.objects.all() #all the objects that are stored in da DB
context={"list": query_set}
return render(request,template_name, context)
```

But when I try to do it as a class based view it doesn't show my Queryset.

in views.py

```
`class RestaurantListView(ListView):
queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()
template_name ="restaurant/restaurantlist.html"`
```

in urls.py

```
path('restaurants', RestaurantListView.as_view()
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your context configs in your `RestaurantListView`, like:

```
class RestaurantListView(ListView):
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()
    template_name ="restaurant/restaurantlist.html"`
    context_object_name = 'list'
```

because it seems you used the old context name in your template codes.